# Pyhtion 2.7 logger in multiple subprocesses doesn't log info into log files

Tags: python-2.7, logging, process, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am using "multiprocessing.Process" to launch multiple subrocesses. Each subprcess is the the same python script, which instantiate Logger and write different levels into log files. As long as it's the same script it creates Logger with the same name in each subprocess.

Also each subprocess has unique ID and logs info including that unique id.

I have found out that log file missing some IDs completely, i.e there is no log output for the whole subprocess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is here:

Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python. If you need to log to a single file from multiple processes, one way of doing this is to have all the processes log to a SocketHandler, and have a separate process which implements a socket server which reads from the socket and logs to file. (If you prefer, you can dedicate one thread in one of the existing processes to perform this function.) This section documents this approach in more detail and includes a working socket receiver which can be used as a starting point for you to adapt in your own applications.

If you are using a recent version of Python which includes the multiprocessing module, you could write your own handler which uses the Lock class from this module to serialize access to the file from your processes. The existing FileHandler and subclasses do not make use of multiprocessing at present, though they may do so in the future. Note that at present, the multiprocessing module does not provide working lock functionality on all platforms (see https://bugs.python.org/issue3770).

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook